# how to stop blinking of text label when button is pressed?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am created two button and two text label and my application is when "1" is pressed "hello" should start blinking and when "2" is pressed "hi" should start blinking and "hello" should stop blinking.it is a demo code of my main project .
Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as Tk
flash_delay = 500  # msec between colour change
flash_colours = ('white', 'red') # Two colours to swap between

def flashColour(object, colour_index):
    object.config(background = flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after(flash_delay, flashColour, object, 1 - colour_index)
def flashColour1(object, colour_index):
    root.txt.config(bg="white")
    object.config(background=flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after(flash_delay, flashColour1, object, 1 - colour_index)
root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")
root.txt = Tk.Text(root, height=2,width=10,font=("TimesNewroman",7,'bold'),
                   background = flash_colours[0])
root.txt.pack()
root.txt.insert(Tk.END,"hello")
root.txt1 = Tk.Text(root, height=2,width=10,font=("TimesNewroman",7,'bold'),
                   background = flash_colours[0])
root.txt1.pack()
root.txt1.insert(Tk.END,"hi")

root.button1=Tk.Button(root,text="1",command = lambda: flashColour(root.txt, 0))
root.button1.pack()
root.button2=Tk.Button(root,text="2",command = lambda: flashColour1(root.txt1, 0))
root.button2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: this is my tkinter window image]

Comment: You can save the ID of the `after(...)`, e.g. `after_1 = root.after(...)`.  Then you can cancel the schedule task by `root.after_cancel(after_1)`.

Comment: @acw1668, as per your suggestion i changed my code to                                              `def flashColour(object, colour_index):
    object.config(background = flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after(flash_delay, flashColour, object, 1 - colour_index)
    flashColour.after_1=root.after(flash_delay, flashColour, object, 1 - colour_index)
def flashColour1(object, colour_index):
    root.after_cancel(flashColour.after_1)
    object.config(background=flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after(flash_delay, flashColour1, object, 1 - colour_index)`.But still it isn't working

Comment: You have two `root.after(...)` in `flashColour(...)`.  Remove the first one.

Comment: @acw1668,one is used to save the ID of after(..)i.e `flashColour.after_1=root.after(...)`

Comment: As you call `after()` twice, there are two **separate** scheduled tasks created.  You cancel one of them, and the other one is still running.

Comment: You mean to use like this `def flashColour(object, colour_index):
    object.config(background = flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after(flash_delay, flashColour, object, 1 - colour_index)
def flashColour1(object, colour_index):
    root.after_cancel(1)
    object.config(background=flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after(flash_delay, flashColour1, object, 1 - colour_index)`

Comment: Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the ID of the `after(...)` task and use `after_cancel(...)` to cancel the scheduled task:

```
def flashColour(object, colour_index):
    object.config(background = flash_colours[colour_index])
    flashColour.after_id = root.after(flash_delay, flashColour, object, 1 - colour_index)

def flashColour1(object, colour_index):
    if hasattr(flashColour, 'after_id'):
        root.after_cancel(flashColour.after_id)
    root.txt.config(bg="white")
    object.config(background=flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after(flash_delay, flashColour1, object, 1 - colour_index)
```

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for your help and valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this... It will work

```
import tkinter as Tk

flash_delay = 500  # msec between colour change
flash_colours = ('white', 'red')  # Two colours to swap between


def flashColour(object, colour_index):
    global a
    object.config(background=flash_colours[colour_index])
    a = root.after(flash_delay, flashColour, object, 1 - colour_index)


def flashColour1(object, colour_index):
    global b
    root.txt.config(bg="white")
    object.config(background=flash_colours[colour_index])
    b = root.after(flash_delay, flashColour1, object, 1 - colour_index)


def stopFlash(object, colour_index):
    root.txt.config(bg="white")
    object.config(background=flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after_cancel(a)


def stopFlash1(object, colour_index):
    root.txt.config(bg="white")
    object.config(background=flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after_cancel(b)


root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x160")
root.txt = Tk.Text(root, height=2, width=10, font=("TimesNewroman", 7, 'bold'),
                   background=flash_colours[0])
root.txt.pack()
root.txt.insert(Tk.END, "hello")
root.txt1 = Tk.Text(root, height=2, width=10, font=("TimesNewroman", 7, 'bold'),
                    background=flash_colours[0])
root.txt1.pack()
root.txt1.insert(Tk.END, "hi")

root.button1 = Tk.Button(root, text="1", command=lambda: flashColour(root.txt, 0))
root.button1.pack()
root.button2 = Tk.Button(root, text="2", command=lambda: flashColour1(root.txt1, 0))
root.button2.pack()
root.button3 = Tk.Button(root, text="Stop1", command=lambda: stopFlash(root.txt, 0))
root.button3.pack()
root.button4 = Tk.Button(root, text="Stop2", command=lambda: stopFlash1(root.txt1, 0))
root.button4.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Used `root.after_cancel(after_id)` to cancel the effect of after !

Comment: ,Thanks for your valuable time but as per my application i can't use separate stop buttons.I have to do stop work through button"2".

Comment: you mean on one click start and other click stop?

Comment: ,no i have two button and two text label ,when i pressed button "1" "hello" text label should start blinking and when i pressed button "2" "hi" label should start blinking and "hello" blink should stop and so on...